# get error in swift side form objective-c side

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

I try to get error object from this function of `ZipArchive`

```
guard  ZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(filePath as String,toDestination: folderPath as String,overwrite: true, password: nil,error: whatShouldGoHere) else 
{
              throw whatShouldGoHere
}
```

My question is how to get back whatShouldGoHere form this `unzipFileAtPath` `Objective-C` function ?

I note that in the define of `unzipFileAtPath` function have access `NSError` object to `whatShouldGoHere` parameter

```
NSError *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"ZipArchiveErrorDomain" code:-1 userInfo:userInformation];

if (error) {
    error = err;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use this library [ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/) to show you how to get the error object from calling objective-c functions.

In this library, it also has the same above function.

```
+ (BOOL)unzipFileAtPath:(NSString *)path toDestination:(NSString *)destination overwrite:(BOOL)overwrite password:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)error;
```

In swift 2.1, you can use [Handling Errors Using Do-Catch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) to get the error object.

```
do {
    try SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(filePath, toDestination: folderPath, overwrite: true, password: nil)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: but it got error:  Cannot invoke 'unzipFileAtPath' with an argument list of type '(String, toDestination: String, overwrite: Bool, password: _)'

Comment: @dellos Which library are you using?

Comment: @dellos yes, should download the latest code. Let's me know if you got any issues.

Comment: thank. i work. i used older library source code. by the way . i m VNes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a function to rethrow the error received from `ZipArchive` don't guard the boolean result but catch the error in a `do - catch` block and throw it.

```
do {
   try SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(filePath as String, 
                      toDestination: folderPath as String, 
                          overwrite: true, 
                           password: nil) 
} catch let error as NSError {
   throw error
}
```

Comment: i think it will not work. casue unzipFileAtPath no have this method. i mean 'unzipFileAtPatch(String,String,Bool,String)'

Comment: The documentation says: *Objective-C methods that produce errors are imported as Swift methods that throw*